# how to build customized existing jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, maven-plugin

for my project i am customizing the jenkins plugin.

when i build the **Junit reporter plugin**, it successfully creates hpi plugin file, since it has no dependencies.

```
for **testng-plugin** build fails. since it needs maven plugin dependencies.
```

how to build the hpi plugin from source of the exisitng customized 
jenkins plugin which has dependencies?

Comment: how are you building it? are you using an IDE or the commandline?

Comment: now currently working through commandline. mean while i am trying in intelliJ IDEA also.

Comment: in commandLine i build the junit realtime reporter plugin in hpi format. please help me to build the testng plugin in commandline